# How many types of functions $f(x)$ satisfy $(f(x))^2$ + $(f'(x))^2 = constant$?

Tags: analysis, functions, constants

I know of two types of $f(x)$ that works.
First one is if $f(x) = c$, of course.
Second one is if it's a trigonometric function: $f(x) = c * \cos(x)$ or $f(x) = c * \sin(x)$.

My question is, are there any other types of functions that satisfy this criteria?

Comment: Solve the separable differential equation $(y')^2=c-y^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Differentiating both sides:

$$2ff'+2f'f''=0$$
$$2f'(f+f'')=0$$

So either $f'=0$, which gives $f(x)=c$, or $f+f''=0$, which gives $f(x)=A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)$.

Comment: So just all vectors in span of $\{ \sin x , \cos x \} $

Comment: @JimmySabater: No. $f(x)=c$ is not in the span of $\{\sin x,\cos x\}$.

Comment: Note that you can also concatenate these solutions (at the points where sine and cosine have zero derivative) in many different ways: for example, I can take $f=1$ for $x \leq 0$ and a cosine for $x \geq 0$. That won't be smooth though, but it's still $C^1$.

Comment: @ThomasBakx: Yes, you are quite right! I started to edit my answer to address your  comment, but then I realised that it would take me all night...

Comment: I think it should be mentioned that constants $A$ and $B$ are not independent: $A^2+B^2=c$. Probably it was even better to represent the solution as $\sqrt{c}\cos(x+\phi)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

$$
f'(x) = \pm\sqrt{c-f(x)^2}
$$

then

$$
dx =\pm\frac{df}{\sqrt{c-f^2}}
$$

giving

$$
x + C_0 = \pm\arctan\left(\frac{f}{\sqrt{ c-f^2}}\right)
$$

etc.